# Что делает и как называется данный оператор в Java

Tags: java

Наткнулся недавно на данную статью https://habr.com/ru/post/430918/ и там есть такой пример кода:

```
    int i = 10;
    i : for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        Log.e(Controller.TAG , "k " + k);
        if (k*k > 10) continue i;
    }
```

Что делает `i : for`?

Comment: `label` *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 4):

Это метка, сюда вернется исполнение кода, если условие `(k*k > 10)` будет истинным.
Сравнимо с оператором `GOTO`.